# Персонаж не ходит плавно при зажатии

Tags: python, turtle

Всем привет! Те, которые используют turtle знают, что персонаж не движется плавно при зажатии. А это мешает геймлею. Как это исправить?

```py
import turtle as tr

pl = tr.Turtle()
pl.pu()

wn = tr.Screen()

def d():
    pl.goto(pl.xcor(),pl.ycor()-10)

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(d,"Down")
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: добавьте time.sleep(0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо чтоб передвижение не зависило от редких импульсов от зажатой клавиши клавиатуры. Поэтому pl.goto запихиваем в цикл while.

```
import turtle as tr

flag = 1

pl = tr.Turtle()
pl.pu()

wn = tr.Screen()

def d():
    global flag
    flag = 1
    while flag:
        pl.goto(pl.xcor(),pl.ycor()-3)

def stop_d():
    global flag
    flag = 0

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(d,"Down")
wn.onkeyrelease(stop_d, "Down")
wn.mainloop()
```

Так правда все остальное зависнет до отпускания клавиши, тогда используем ontimer:

```
import turtle as tr

flag = 1

pl = tr.Turtle()
pl.pu()

wn = tr.Screen()

def d():
    global flag
    if flag:
        pl.goto(pl.xcor(),pl.ycor()-3)
        wn.ontimer(d, 1)
    else:
        flag = 1

def stop_d():
    global flag
    flag = 0

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(d,"Down")
wn.onkeyrelease(stop_d, "Down")
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Здравсвуйте! Спасибо, помогло! Но есть здесь маленькая проблема - при долгой зажатии персонаж ездит и не останавливается после того как отпустил клавишу как будто у него тормоз сломался.

Comment: @Master's Time Лучше создайте новый вопрос с частью кода, на котором можно воспроизвести возникающую новую проблему.